# Conversion from stack to queue or Queue to stack?

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue, computer-science, recursive-datastructures

Can we convert **Stacks** into **Queues** and **Queues** to **Stack** ???

I am newbie to computer science and StackOverflow, so if you feel question is not appropriate then comment it with your suggestions

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  The community favors question from posters who post what they have tried. Have you tried converting a queue to a stack?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert?" Do just want to take all the elements from a stack, and build a new queue from them? Or do you somehow want to treat a single data structure as though it is both a stack and a queue?

Comment: using both stack and quees as single data struture ...

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a [double-ended queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue), also known as a deque.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion is not possible.
but yes, you can create if you want, but it doesn't make sense let see with an example.

if you want to create a stack using a queue
1. take 2 queues (queue1, queue2).
2. To add element 
   add an element in queue1.
   add all the elements of queue2 in queue1
   (reason queue follow FIFI but stack follows LIFO to maintain the order we need to take
   two queues)
3. swap both queue.
4. Now you will be able to take out element from the queue which is inserted in the end.